# Java How to assign "Logical And Operator" to a "boolean variable"

Tags: java, logical-operators

It is just my curiosity whether I can do something like

```
private static boolean and = &&;
```

I wonder whether a "logical and operator" can be assigned to a "boolean variable".

P.S. I can't compile the sentence, because it already gave an error. Since variable initialization  requires tokens and && is not a token.

Comment: Did you try compiling this? You can get your answer in the output.

Comment: No? Unless you mean something like: private static int x = 0xFF&0xCB; or something...

Comment: I can't compile the sentence, since && is not a token. I wonder whether && can be casted as a token.

Comment: Even not mentioning Java cannot do it, what you are doing is irrational: You are assigning an "operator" to a "boolean".  What makes you think it should work?

Comment: Well if you look at that point of view casting float to int is also irrational. For example: declaring ArrayList<T> is also irrational etc...

Comment: @AhmetTavli Casting a float to an int is very much rational and done a lot, as is the declaration of a generic container type. Casting an float to a generic container type on the other hand is irrational (or better: it doesn't have any useful meaning)

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this in Java. If you have your heart set on doing something like this, try using the preprocessor command `#define` in C or C++.

Beware though - this is NOT recommended as you'll have a lot of trouble debugging and finding other developers to work on code with you.

You may even end up with your own entry on TheDailyWTF (like [this](http://thedailywtf.com/articles/The_Secret_to_Better_C), [this](http://thedailywtf.com/articles/_0x23_include__0x22_pascal_0x2e_h_0x22_), [this](http://thedailywtf.com/articles/SUCSESS), [this](http://thedailywtf.com/articles/The-Disgruntled-Bomb), or [this](http://thedailywtf.com/articles/_0x23_define_1_as_2))

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example using English grammar, the way I see it:

"And" and "True" are different parts of speech. "True" is an adjective, so you can say, "That is true." "And" is a conjunction, so it does not make sense to say "That is and."

Same thing with `&&` and `true`. `&&` is an *operator* "part of speech," whereas `true` is a *value* "part of speech." Because of this, it doesn't make sense to set a `boolean` *value* to an *operator*. Perhaps something like this could be done, if instead of `boolean and = &&` you could type `BooleanOperator and = &&`; however, there is no such type or functionality in Java (see Chris's answer about C).

Comment: Concise and clear explanation. A boolean type variable can either take true or false and there is no way you can cast && operator as true or false in java

Answer (score 0):

For years people have wanted sentence like programming. If you can make a language that does that, then awesome! However java cannot be converted to sentence like programming. Perhaps you could write a string modifying class that assigns certain words to other characters that it would then input into whatever text editor you are using. Good luck debugging though!

Comment: Isn't this sort of thing possible in C++ with `#define`? Like `#define not !=` from a quick search of [dailywtf](http://thedailywtf.com/articles/_0x23_include__0x22_pascal_0x2e_h_0x22_)